# Valor de variável está alterando automaticamente

Tags: python, array, variáveis, numpy, declaração-de-variável

Estou com uma dúvida em relação a atribuição de valores em variáveis. Eu criei o seguinte código para solução de sistemas de equação pelo método iterativo de Gauss-Jacobi:

```
A = np.array([[2., -1.], [1., 2.]]) # Matriz de coeficientes
B = np.array([[1.], [3.]]) # Vetor de constantes
X = np.array([[0.], [0.]]) # Estimativa inicial
EA = 10**(-2) # Erro absoluto da solução do problema
erro = 1

while (erro > EA):
    Xp = tuple(X)
    print("\nO valor de Xp é:", Xp) # Aqui Xp está apresentando um valor
    for i in range(len(A)):
        s = 0
        for j in range(len(A)):
            if (i != j):
                s += A[i,j]*Xp[j]
        print("\nO valor de s é:", s)
        X[i] = (B[i] - s)/A[i,i]
    print("\nO valor de Xp é:", Xp) # Aqui Xp está apresentando outro valor, sendo que eu não alterei ele
    print("\nO valor de X é:", X)
    erro = np.amax(np.absolute(X - np.asarray(Xp)))
```

Inicialmente, defini que Xp apresentasse o mesmo valor de X. Em seguida, altero apenas o valor de X.

Sempre que executo este código, o valor de Xp está alterando automaticamente, sempre que eu mudo o valor de X. Tentei fazer com que Xp seja uma tupla para que ele não altere automaticamente o seu valor, mas não obtive êxito. Qual a explicação para isso e como corrigir?

Ao longo do código, coloquei comentários indicando onde está ocorrendo o meu problema.

Comment: Creio que vc criou uma referência e não uma cópia. Use `Xp = tuple(np.copy(X))`, verifique o resultado e

Comment: Resolveu, muito obrigado!

Comment: que bom que resolveu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caro,

De forma rápida, conforme disse no comentário:

> "vc criou uma referência e não uma cópia. Use `Xp = tuple(np.copy(X))`"

## Explicação

Conforme coloquei no comentário, você criou uma referência para a variável já existente ao invés de fazer uma cópia.

Vários tipos do Python possuem esta característica. Veja abaixo:

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> b = a
>>> b.append(2)
>>> b
[1, 2]
>>> a
[1, 2]
>>>
```

Perceba que a lista `a` foi alterada ao incluir um item na lista `b`. Esta última (`b`) é apenas uma referência para a lista `a`.

Para fazer cópia de uma lista (e vários outros tipos de variáveis, existe o método `copy`. Vaja abaixo:

```
>>> c = a.copy()
>>> c
[1, 2]
>>> c.append(3)
>>> c
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a
[1, 2]
```

Desta vez, a lista `c` recebeu uma cópia da lista `a` e sendo assim, ao incluir um item na lista `c` não ocasionou nenhuma mudança na lista `a`.

Veja abaixo que o mesmo acontece com `set`

```
>>> s = set(a)
>>> s
{1, 2}
>>> z = s
>>> z.add(3)
>>> z
{1, 2, 3}
>>> s
{1, 2, 3}
>>> w = s.copy()
>>> w.add(4)
>>> w
{1, 2, 3, 4}
>>> s
{1, 2, 3}
```

Primeiro foi criado uma referência (`z`) e depois uma cópia (`w`)

Não vou alongar este post, mas acrescento que o mesmo acontece com dicionários.

Você pode checar por meio da função `id`

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> id(a)
4313065216
>>> b = a
>>> id(b)
4313065216
```

Perceba que é o mesmo `id`

Entendido o conceito de referência e cópia, partimos para o porquê disso.

Existem tipos **mutáveis** e **imutáveis**. Ao associar uma variável do tipo mutável à uma outra varíavel, isso cria uma referência. Por outro lado, ao associar uma variável do tipo imutável à uma outra varíavel, isso cria uma cópia.

### Tipo de Objetos Mutáveis

1. list
2. Set
3. Dictionary
4. bytearray
5. user defined classes

### Tipo de Objetos Imutáveis

1. int
2. float
3. decimal
4. complex
5. bool
6. tuple
7. range
8. bytes
9. string

Espero ter ajudado