# Utilizar uma matriz 30 x 3 usando class, def, parâmetros - Python

Tags: python, classes, matriz

A intenção aqui é utilizar uma matriz capaz de armazenar em cada posição todas as informações referentes a um serviço prestado (número, valor, código do serviço, código do cliente). Cada linha representa um dia do mês. Então, devo utilizar uma matriz 30 × 3. Segue o código:

```
class TipoServico:
    codigo = 0
    descricao = ''

class PrestacaoServico:
    numero = 0
    valor = 0.0
    cod_servico = 0
    cod_cliente = 0

def cadastrar_tipos_servicos(vets):
    for i in range(4):
        s = TipoServico()
        s.codigo = input('Digite o código do serviço: ')
        s.descricao = input('Digite a descrição do serviço: ')
        vets.append(s)
    return vets

def consultar_tipos_servicos(vets):
    for i in range(len(vets)):
        print('Código: ',vets[i].codigo,'\tDescrição do servico: ',vets[i].descricao)

def servicos_prestados(vetm):
  x = PrestacaoServico()
  total_de_dias = 30
  total_de_servicos = 3
  for lin in range(total_de_dias):
    for col in range(total_de_servicos):
      x.numero = int(input('Informe o número: '))
      x.valor = float(input('Informe o valor: R$'))
      x.cod_servico = int(input('Informe o código do serviço: '))
      x.cod_cliente = int(input('Informe o código do cliente: '))
      vetm.append(x)
    break
  return vetm

def consultar_servicos_prestados(vetm):
  for i in range(len(vetm)):
    print('Número: ',vetm[i].numero,'\tValor: R$',vetm[i].valor,'\tCódigo do serviço:',vetm[i].cod_servico,'\tCódigo do cliente:',vetm[i].cod_cliente)

def main():
    vetServico = []
    matriz = []
    while True:
        print('Menu de opções')
        print('1. Cadastrar os tipos de serviços')
        print('2. Mostrar todos os tipos de serviço')
        print('3. Cadastrar os serviços prestados')
        print('4. Mostrar todos os serviços prestados')
        print('5. Mostrar os serviços prestados em determinado dia')
        print('6. Mostrar os serviços prestados dentro de um intervalo de valor')
        print('7. Mostrar um relatório geral (separado por dia)')
        print('8. Sair')
        opcao = int(input('Digite a opção desejada: '))
        if opcao == 1:
            vetServico = cadastrar_tipos_servicos(vetServico)
        elif opcao == 2:
            consultar_tipos_servicos(vetServico)
        elif opcao == 3:
            matriz = servicos_prestados(matriz)
        elif opcao == 4:
            consultar_servicos_prestados(matriz)
        elif opcao == 5:
            print('Opção 5')
        elif opcao == 6:
            print('Opção 6')
        elif opcao == 7:
            print('Opção 7')
        else:
            break
main()
```

Comment: e qual é a pergunta? Está dando algum erro?

Comment: Quando peço para mostrar todos os serviços prestados, resulta em 3x:
Número:  30  Valor: R$ 300.0  Código do serviço: 3  Código do cliente: 3
Ou seja, só está armazenando os últimos dados colocados.

Comment: Veja se resolve alterar a linha abaixo da `opcao == 1` de `vetServico = cadastrar_tipos_servicos(vetServico)` para `vetServico.append(cadastrar_tipos_servicos(vetServico))`
Isso, pois vc tem que adicionar ``a sua lista.

Comment: O problema está na opcao 3 e 4, ou seja, na `def servicos_prestados(vetm)` e `def consultar_servicos_prestados(vetm)`. A opcao 1 e 2 está funcionando normalmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baseado nos comentários entendi a questão.

Uma classe definida pelo programador é um tipo **mutável**

Leia este [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/478735/valor-de-vari%c3%a1vel-est%c3%a1-alterando-automaticamente/478900#478900) para maiores detalhes.

Modifique a função `servicos_prestados` para

```
def servicos_prestados(vetm):
  total_de_dias = 30
  total_de_servicos = 3
  for lin in range(total_de_dias):
    for col in range(total_de_servicos):
      x = PrestacaoServico()
      x.numero = int(input('Informe o número: '))
      x.valor = float(input('Informe o valor: R$'))
      x.cod_servico = int(input('Informe o código do serviço: '))
      x.cod_cliente = int(input('Informe o código do cliente: '))
      vetm.append(x)
    break    # entendo que este break é para questões de teste
  return vetm
```

Expliocação:

Sendo uma `user defined class` um tipo mutável, o último valor sobrepõe o anterior

### Código similar ao seu

```
class MinhaClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.valor = None

l = []
meu_object = MinhaClass()
for i in range(3):
    meu_object.valor = i
    l.append(meu_object)
    print(l)
```

A saída deste programa será algo como

```
[<__main__.MinhaClass object at 0x7f8a8d87bb50>]
[<__main__.MinhaClass object at 0x7f8a8d87bb50>, <__main__.MinhaClass object at 0x7f8a8d87bb50>]
[<__main__.MinhaClass object at 0x7f8a8d87bb50>, <__main__.MinhaClass object at 0x7f8a8d87bb50>, <__main__.MinhaClass object at 0x7f8a8d87bb50>]
```

**Repare que MinhaClass dentro da lista sempre aponda para o mesmo endereço de memória**

Sendo assim, veja o resultado:

```
>>> [o.valor for o in l]
[2, 2, 2]
```

**Nota**: 2 é o último valor por causa do range.

### Modificando o código

```
class MinhaClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.valor = None

l = []
for i in range(3):
    meu_object = MinhaClass()   # reaproveitando o nome da variável, mas na verdade, criando uma nova
    meu_object.valor = i
    l.append(meu_object)
    print(l)
```

A saída deste código seria algo como

```
[<__main__.MinhaClass object at 0x7f8a8d87bc10>]
[<__main__.MinhaClass object at 0x7f8a8d87bc10>, <__main__.MinhaClass object at 0x7f8a8d87bb50>]
[<__main__.MinhaClass object at 0x7f8a8d87bc10>, <__main__.MinhaClass object at 0x7f8a8d87bb50>, <__main__.MinhaClass object at 0x7f8a8d87bbd0>]
```

Os valores na lista como esperado

```
>>> [o.valor for o in l]
[0, 1, 2]
```

Espero ter ajudado