# Não existe nenhum erro na execução do código, porém o retorno que estou tendo na tabela do excel é que é o problema

Tags: python, python-3.x, xls, lib

Estou com um problema no retorno do meu código. Não me é retornado nenhum erro na execução, porém o problema disso é o retorno na tabela do Excel. Estou fazendo um estudo de caso da minha faculdade e o sistema se trata sobre o cadastro de clientes e encomenda. O código da classe e do objeto logo abaixo:

**Classe**

```
class Cliente:
    def __init__(self, nome, s_nome, tel, email, social_n, endereco, data_cad):
        self.set_nome(nome)
        self.set_s_nome(s_nome)
        self.set_tel(tel)
        self.set_email(email)
        self.set_social_n(social_n)
        self.set_endereco(endereco)
        self.set_data_cad(data_cad)

    # SETs dos dados do cliente

    def set_nome(self, nome):
        self.nome = nome

    def set_s_nome(self, s_nome):
        self.s_nome = s_nome

    def set_tel(self, tel):
        self.tel = tel

    def set_email(self, email):
        self.email = email

    def set_social_n(self, social_n):
        self.social_n = social_n
    
    def set_endereco(self, endereco):
        self.endereco = endereco

    def set_data_cad(self, data_cad):
        self.data_cad = data_cad

    # GET para retornar o "database"

    def get_database(self,rows):
        one_cliente = []
        for n in range(rows):
            one_cliente.append({
                'id': n + 1,
                'nome':self.nome,
                'sobrenome':self.s_nome,
                'telefone':self.tel,
                'email':self.email,
                'rede_social':self.social_n,
                'endereco':self.endereco,
                'data_de_cadastro':self.data_cad
            })
        return one_cliente
```

**outro codigo**

```
import os
import xlwt
import xlrd
from datetime import date
from class_cliente import Cliente

def main():
    cont = 1

    print('''\
        O que deseja fazer?
        [1] Tabela de Clientes
        [2] Tabela de Encomendas
        [3] Excluir Cadastro
        [4] Relatório Excel
        [5] Sair
        ''')

    opcGeral = int(input('Digite Aqui: '))
    while True:
        if opcGeral == 1:

            nome = input('Nome do cliente: ')
            s_nome = input('Sobrenome do cliente: ')
            tel = input('Telefone pra conta: ')
            email = input('email: ')
            social_n = input('Rede: ')
            endereco = input('Endereço: ')                
            data_cad = date.today()

            workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
            worksheet = workbook.add_sheet("cliente")

            dado_cliente = Cliente(nome, s_nome, tel, email, social_n, endereco, data_cad)
            cont_cadas = dado_cliente.get_database(cont) 
            cont += 1

        elif opcGeral == 2:
            pass

        elif opcGeral == 4:
            worksheet.write(0,0,u'ID')
            worksheet.write(0,1,u'NOME')
            worksheet.write(0,2,u'SOBRENOME')
            worksheet.write(0,3,u'TELEFONE')
            worksheet.write(0,4,u'EMAIL')
            worksheet.write(0,5,u'REDE SOCIAL')
            worksheet.write(0,6,u'ENDEREÇO')
            worksheet.write(0,7,u'DATA DO CADASTRO')

            for i, cliente_one in enumerate(cont_cadas):
                worksheet.write(i + 1, 0, label = cliente_one['id'])
                worksheet.write(i + 1, 1, label = cliente_one['nome'])
                worksheet.write(i + 1, 2, label = cliente_one['sobrenome'])
                worksheet.write(i + 1, 3, label = cliente_one['telefone'])
                worksheet.write(i + 1, 4, label = cliente_one['email'])
                worksheet.write(i + 1, 5, label = cliente_one['rede_social'])
                worksheet.write(i + 1, 6, label = cliente_one['endereco'])
                worksheet.write(i + 1, 7, label = cliente_one['data_de_cadastro'],style=xlwt.easyxf(num_format_str='dd/mm/yyyy'))

            workbook.save('cliente.xls')


        opcGeral = input('Cadastrar mais clientes: [S/N]')
        if opcGeral.lower() == 's' :
            print('''\
        O que deseja fazer?
        [1] Tabela de Clientes
        [2] Tabela de Encomendas
        [3] Excluir Cadastro
        [4] Relatório Excel
        [5] Sair
        ''')

            opcGeral = int(input('Digite Aqui: '))

        else:
            break

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**OBS: O segundo código ainda não esta terminado**

Eu estou usando a lib xlwt para escrever no Excel só que quando vou executar o código quando começo a cadastrar os clientes fica normal e insere os dados normalmente, porém quando eu realizo dois cadastros ao invés de escrever no Excel as duas pessoas cadastradas ela acaba escrevendo duas vezes a ultima pessoa cadastrada... gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado.

Comment: `User defined class` é do tipo mutável. Leia este [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/478735/valor-de-vari%C3%A1vel-est%C3%A1-alterando-automaticamente) pois acredito que seja esse o problema.

Comment: Como você está executando o programa quando percebe o erro? Você cadastra um cliente, salva no excel, cadastra o segundo e salva no excell de novo?  Ou você cadastra duas vezes e salva duas vezes?

Comment: salva somente uma vez cadastra várias e salva uma vez.

Comment: Ok, já entendi o seu problema. Você percebe que `cont_cadas` é uma lista que só contém o cadastro de um cliente? Você não está guardando as informações de cada cliente mas de um único.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu problema é que a sua lista `one_cliente` que estava sendo gerada na classe `Cliente` continha n-vezes o mesmo cliente, com um id diferente. Para resolver isso eu sugiro que você use uma variável estática da classe `Cliente` para armazenar cada novo cliente cadastrado. Para isso basta criar a lista vazia `one_cliente` fora da função `get_database` e se referir a ela como `Cliente.one_cliente` como no exemplo abaixo:

```
class Cliente:
    one_cliente = []

    def __init__(self, nome, s_nome, tel, email, social_n, endereco, data_cad):
        self.set_nome(nome)
        self.set_s_nome(s_nome)
        self.set_tel(tel)
        self.set_email(email)
        self.set_social_n(social_n)
        self.set_endereco(endereco)
        self.set_data_cad(data_cad)

    # SETs dos dados do cliente

    def set_nome(self, nome):
        self.nome = nome

    def set_s_nome(self, s_nome):
        self.s_nome = s_nome

    def set_tel(self, tel):
        self.tel = tel

    def set_email(self, email):
        self.email = email

    def set_social_n(self, social_n):
        self.social_n = social_n
    
    def set_endereco(self, endereco):
        self.endereco = endereco

    def set_data_cad(self, data_cad):
        self.data_cad = data_cad

    # GET para retornar o "database"

    def get_database(self, id):
        Cliente.one_cliente.append({
            'id': id,
            'nome':self.nome,
            'sobrenome':self.s_nome,
            'telefone':self.tel,
            'email':self.email,
            'rede_social':self.social_n,
            'endereco':self.endereco,
            'data_de_cadastro':self.data_cad
        })
        return Cliente.one_cliente
```

dessa forma você não precisa alterar mas nada no resto do código