# Como criar dataframes independentes no Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Estou com um problema em python, como crio dataframe independentes?
O que me ocorre:

```
>>> PREMISSAS['QTD_ESTOQUE_MEDIO']
0          628.5
1        20202.5
2        42902.0
3        50036.0
4         8561.5
          ...   
12646    14356.5
12647     1236.0
12648     9997.5
12649     5181.5
12650     5061.5

>>> PREMISSAS_STK_MAIS_5 = PREMISSAS
>>> PREMISSAS_STK_MAIS_10 = PREMISSAS
>>> PREMISSAS_STK_MENOS_5 = PREMISSAS
>>> PREMISSAS_STK_MENOS_10 = PREMISSAS
>>> 
>>> PREMISSAS_STK_MAIS_5['QTD_ESTOQUE_MEDIO'] = PREMISSAS_STK_MAIS_5['QTD_ESTOQUE_MEDIO']*1.05
>>> PREMISSAS_STK_MAIS_10['QTD_ESTOQUE_MEDIO'] = PREMISSAS_STK_MAIS_10['QTD_ESTOQUE_MEDIO']*1.1
>>> PREMISSAS_STK_MENOS_5['QTD_ESTOQUE_MEDIO'] = PREMISSAS_STK_MENOS_5['QTD_ESTOQUE_MEDIO']*0.95
>>> PREMISSAS_STK_MENOS_10['QTD_ESTOQUE_MEDIO'] = PREMISSAS_STK_MENOS_10['QTD_ESTOQUE_MEDIO']*0.9

>>> PREMISSAS['QTD_ESTOQUE_MEDIO']
0          620.659463
1        19950.473813
2        42366.797550
3        49411.800900
4         8454.695288
             ...     
12646    14177.402663
12647     1220.580900
12648     9872.781188
12649     5116.860788
12650     4998.357788
Name: QTD_ESTOQUE_MEDIO, Length: 12651, dtype: float64
>>> PREMISSAS_STK_MAIS_5['QTD_ESTOQUE_MEDIO']
0          620.659463
1        19950.473813
2        42366.797550
3        49411.800900
4         8454.695288
             ...     
12646    14177.402663
12647     1220.580900
12648     9872.781188
12649     5116.860788
12650     4998.357788
Name: QTD_ESTOQUE_MEDIO, Length: 12651, dtype: float64
>>> PREMISSAS_STK_MENOS_10['QTD_ESTOQUE_MEDIO']
0          620.659463
1        19950.473813
2        42366.797550
3        49411.800900
4         8454.695288
             ...     
12646    14177.402663
12647     1220.580900
12648     9872.781188
12649     5116.860788
12650     4998.357788
Name: QTD_ESTOQUE_MEDIO, Length: 12651, dtype: float64
```

Meu objetivo é criar data frames com cenários diferentes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
novo_df = df_original.copy(deep=True)
```

Atribuição de variável no Python nem sempre cria um objeto novo, apenas aloca uma "etiqueta" nova para um objeto que já existe

Comment: Caro, para entender melhor sobre objetos mutáveis e imutáveis. Leia a resposta deste [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/478735/valor-de-vari%C3%A1vel-est%C3%A1-alterando-automaticamente)

Answer (score -1):

Use condições para atribuir um DataFrame ao novo

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"PREMISSAS": range(1,100)})

>>> df
    PREMISSAS
0           1
1           2
2           3
3           4
4           5
..        ...
94         95
95         96
96         97
97         98
98         99
```

Premissas maiores que 5 e menores que 10

```
>>> df1 = df[(df["PREMISSAS"] < 10) & (df["PREMISSAS"] > 5)]

>>> df1
   PREMISSAS
5          6
6          7
7          8
8          9
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Entendo que o objetivo da pergunta era criar DataFrames a partir de determinadas condições. A pessoa que votou negativo nesta questão poderia comentar o porque a resposta não atende? Assim posso melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Porque a pergunta não era sobre como filtrar um DataFrame, mas como eliminar a retroalimentação dos DataFrame. O DataFrame ```PREMISSAS_STK_MAIS_5 ``` foi criado a partir de ```PREMISSAS```, mas quando alterei  ```PREMISSAS_STK_MAIS_5``` ocorreu de as alterações passarem para ```PREMISSAS```.

Comment: Bem, talvez eu tenha sido traído pela frase ao final do post `Meu objetivo é criar data frames com cenários diferentes.`. A resposta dada por mim, atende melhor que a utilização do método `.copy(deep=True)`, pois caso você tenha um Dataframe com milhões de linhas e fizer cópias do mesmo primeiro para depois filtrar, vc poderá ter um "leak" de memória. O ideal é criar um novo DataFrame, conforme eu sugeri, já filtrando. Caso ainda assim você ache que a resposta não atende, sem problemas... Não deixe de ler a resposta sobre objetos mutáveis e imutáveis que indiquei em sua resposta.