# Como unir vários DataFrames em um único arquivo excel

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Tenho um código de WebSacraping, utilizando o loop `for`, ele busca e retorna varios DataFrames com as informações, gostaria de salva-las em excel, porem quando utilizo a fórmula `to_excel`, ele salva substituindo a informação anterior, preciso que ele continue preenchendo a planilha com os dados novos ao invés de substituílos,
Segue Código:

```
for i in dados_gsheet.index:
      produto = dados_gsheet.loc[i, 'Descritivo']
      browser.get('https://shopping.google.com/?nord=1')
      pesquisa = WebDriverWait(browser, 120).until(lambda x: x.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="REsRA"]'))
      pesquisa.send_keys(produto)
      pesquisa.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
  try:
       Item_1 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
      '//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span/a/div[1]/h4').text
       Valor_1 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
      '//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/div[1]/a[1]/div[2]/span/span/span[1]/span').text
       Link_1 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
      '//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/div[1]/a[2]').get_attribute('href')
       Item_2 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
      '//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span/a/div[1]/h4').text
       Valor_2 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
     '//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/div[1]/a[1]/div[2]/span/span/span[1]/span').text
       Link_2 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
     '//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/div[1]/a[2]').get_attribute('href')
       Item_3 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
     '//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/span/a/div[1]/h4').text
       Valor_3 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
     '//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/div[1]/a[1]/div[2]/span/span/span[1]/span').text
       Link_3 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
     '//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/div[1]/a[2]').get_attribute('href')
       Item_4 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
     '//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/span/a/div[1]/h4').text
       Valor_4 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
     '//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/div[1]/a[1]/div[2]/span/span/span[1]/span').text
       Link_4 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
     '//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/div[1]/a[2]').get_attribute('href')
       Item_5 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
     '//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/span/a/div[1]/h4').text
       Valor_5 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
     '//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/div[1]/a[1]/div[2]/span/span/span[1]/span').text
       Link_5 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
     '//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/div[1]/a[2]').get_attribute('href')
       pro = Item_1, Item_2, Item_3, Item_4, Item_5 
       val = Valor_1, Valor_2, Valor_3, Valor_4, Valor_5
       lin = Link_1, Link_2, Link_3, Link_4, Link_5
       Conclusão = pd.DataFrame({'Produto': pro,'Preço': val,'Url': lin})
       display(Conclusão)
       planilha1 = Conclusão.to_excel('teste.xlsx')
       time.sleep(15)
  except NoSuchElementException:
       print('Não encontrado')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O dataframe é um objeto mutável, veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/478735/valor-de-vari%C3%A1vel-est%C3%A1-alterando-automaticamente)

A solução para seu caso é:

```
# cria um objeto tipo lista
dfs = []

# itera
for i in dados_gsheet.index:
    (...)
    # adiciona resultado à lista
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame({'Produto': pro,'Preço': val,'Url': lin}))

# após o loop concatena dfs
df_final = pd.concat(dfs)

# salva em Excel
df_final.to_excel('teste.xlsx')
```

**IMPORTANTE**

Caso você associe o resultado a uma variável e depois acrescente a mesma à lista **NÃO** funcionará

```
# ISSO É ERRADO
for i in .....:
     conclusao = pd.DataFrame(.....)
     dfs.append(conclusao)

df_final = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Caso você queira fazer algo como acima, apague a variável da memória.

```
# POSSÍVEL
for i in .....:
     conclusao = pd.DataFrame(.....)
     dfs.append(conclusao)
     del(conclusao)

df_final = pd.concat(dfs)
```